# Meaning of the phrasal verb "dial in" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

The following excerpt is from this [article](http://robertsontrainingsystems.com/blog/stop-missing-lifts/).

> Training in this fashion will not only **dial in** and perfect technique, but you’ll be optimizing your training as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dial in something to a process is to adjust or control the process to achieve a desired outcome, like someone turning a dial on the control panel of a machine.

> Dial in
>
> (also be/get dialled in) (informal)
>
> to direct all your effort and
>   attention on to what you are trying to achieve, so you perform as well
>   as you can.

[Dial in (Oxford)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dial-in)

Comment: "perfect" could be a verb; they're dialling in their technique and perfecting it.

Comment: Agreed. See edited answer.

Comment: I think a person can be dialed in but I think the usage in the question is questionable. I can't see that training dials something in. It just does not work for me. I agree with your explanation but would never accept that in anything I was editing.

Comment: I completely agree.